# grep several strings from gz file

Tags: bash, grep, gunzip

What is the best way to extract lines from a very large gz file that match multiple strings in a second file?

I've tried, which works for that string and surrounding:

```
gunzip -c /myfolder/large_file.gz | grep -B 50 "33754548"  > /myfolder/specific_linesfrom_large_files.txt
```

However, sometimes the strings needed are not in 50 lines near, so I attempted:

```
gunzip -c /myfolder/large_file.gz | grep  -F  /myfolder/multiple_strings.txt  > /myfolder/specific_linesfrom_large_files.txt
```

Which didn't work, any suggestions?

for example, the **multiple_strings.txt** file might contain:

```
16804029
42061608
42069963
42072123
177479064
177420374
```

Comment: I think you mean `-f`, not `-F`.

Comment: how about bzcat and grep ?

Comment: And how about `zgrep` instead decompressing yourself?

Comment: Are you running this command in Linux or Unix? Try zgrep the same way you run grep

Comment: You can search for lines containing any of `StringA`, `PatternB` or `ThingC` with `grep -E "StringA|PatternB|ThingC"` by the way.

Comment: I have 23 files, which are 1.4 TB total, decompressing isn't preferred. I'm running Linux.

Comment: I tried the original commands with -f (instead of -F) and zgrep. Both worked, however, -f run time was faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `zgrep` to search into compressed files. There are also other commands like `bzgrep` (for bzip2 files), `xzgrep` etc for compressed files.

```
zgrep -f match_strings.txt file.gz
```

`-f` is the flag for reading the patterns from a specified file.

Answer (score 0):

```
gunzip -c /myfolder/large_file.gz | grep -f /myfolder/multiple_strings.txt > /myfolder/specific_linesfrom_large_files.txt
```

Using also -x you search for exact pattern, for example if you search 123 you can match 1234, 123 etc. using -x you match only 123.